# Namespace fails to unload in R

Tags: r, namespaces, onunload

I am having trouble unloading the namespace for a package I created in R.  Every time I try to do so I get the following error:

> Error in .mergeMethodsTable(generic, mtable, get(tname, envir = env),  :
>        trying to get slot "defined" from an object of a basic class ("environment") with no
>        slots
>   Calls: unloadNamespace ...  -> .updateMethodsInTable -> .mergeMethodsTable

Here are the results of a call to traceback() after the above error occurs.

```
>4: .mergeMethodsTable(generic, mtable, get(tname, envir = env), attach)
 3: .updateMethodsInTable(fdef, where, attach)
 2: methods:::cacheMetaData(ns, FALSE, ns)
 1: unloadNamespace("coleXcms")
```

I honestly have tried everything I can think of, but to no avail.  I'm pretty new to R so I was hoping someone might be able to help me.

Also, don't know if this will be useful, but here is my package's unloading hook. (The name of my package is coleXcms)

```
.onUnload <- function(libpath) {  
    mzR:::rampCloseAll()  
    library.dynam.unload("coleXcms", libpath)
}
```

Comment: It might help to provide the result of `traceback()` after the error occurs.

Comment: Updated post to show results of traceback @MartinMorgan

Comment: Sorry, Cole, it's too hard for me to figure out from a distance; if your package (or a minimal version of it) were in some public place that might make some trouble-shooting possible...

Comment: @MarginMorgan Threw it on github.   https://github.com/ColeWunderlich/coleXcms

Comment: Also, this is sort of a hack of Xcms where I modified a few things to improve the run-time significantly.  It may be possible that I broke something in the process....

Answer (score 1):

The function I have used with success is `unloadNamespace`. It appears that `library.dynam.unload` is designed to remove the DLLs but it's not clear to me that it will remove the rest of a package.

Comment: The above error is what I get when I call detatch (package:coleXcms, unload=T) which I believe results in a call to unloadNamespace at some point. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can attempt to verify your understanding by typing `detach` at the console. I think there are discussions in the R-help archives that make a distinction between the effects of `detach` and `unloadNamepsace`. My unconfirmed memory was that `unloadNamespace` may succeed when `detach` fails ... here's where I may have gathered that impression: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.general/111050/match=unloadnamespace+detach   I am unable to explain why but can report from experience that `unloadNamespace` succeeds when `detach` fails.